# Is it possible to transfer files via ZModem over USB?

Tags: .net, usb, transfer, zmodem

And especially are there .NET libraries available for the purpose?  Two hours of Google searches have turned up nothing so I'm not optimistic, but ...

The big question: is it even possible to use ZModem over USB?

TIA.

Comment: Wow ZModem  this was developed in the 80's when Bulletin Board Systems were widely used?  Didnt know people were still actively using it.  Curious whats the application of this?  lol sorry this question just make me think of TradeWars and other text based games from back in the day

Comment: @John: I've used xmodem as an upload for data on microcontrollers. Don't knock old technology ;)

Comment: @theatrus...I wasnt knocking it,  This quesiton just sparked some memories.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to transfer. USB is a bus which has multiple transfer modes (packetized data), including several standard ones such as CDC (Communications Device Class) which Windows will emulate as a COM port.

However, USB is also master->slave. You cannot simply connect two computers together using USB with just a cable. The "transfer cables" they sell contain active electronics to bridge the two hosts together, but are proprietary.

In short, yes, you can use ZModem over USB since ZModem is basically a byte stream with error recovery information, which can be sent in any matter of methods. You could even print it out and send it by carrier pigeon, though it is not optimized for this (as it requires bi-directional communication). The complexity lies in the USB portion, and the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Normal USB modems fakes a com port. It should be trivial to write to a COM port. I think the problem figuring out which port to use.